# Split a value of different data types cell array based upon a delimiter

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, cell

Considering a cell array:

```
MyValues = {'HI, HOW ARE YOU, NICE TO MEET YOU, 1.32, -0.54BC, AUF WIEDERSEHEN'
            'HELLO, YES I am fine, Thank you for asking, 0.666HG, 67@#, 84'     }
```

And I want to split this cell array with values separated by the delimiter (comma). Something like this:

```
NewValues = { 'HI'
              'HOW ARE YOU'
              'NICE TO MEET YOU'
              '1.32'
              '-0.54BC'
              'AUF WIEDERSEHEN'
              'HELLO'
              'YES I am fine'
              'Thank you for asking'
              '0.66HG'
              '67@#'
              '84'      }
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten what your question was. What exactly are you trying to ask?

Comment: @rayryeng Thank you, I have edited my question again

Comment: I still have no idea what you are asking.  It looks like you have a 2 element cell array where each element is a string. Do you desire to create a `N` element cell array where you want to break up the strings based on the comma as the delimiter?

Comment: I am getting an output of cell array with values such as `HI, HOW ARE YOU, NICE TO MEET YOU, 1.32......` In one row, I want to rearrange into each row, using some specified matlab function.

Comment: @rayryeng yes exactly, but its not just strings, it has sample time, characters, etc

Comment: Still having trouble understanding what you want.  So you have a cell array of size `m x n`.  What does each cell element contain? What is your desired result with this cell array? I apologize but the phrasing of your question and the example inputs and outputs you provided are quite unclear.

Comment: @rayryeng Hi, I edited the question again

Comment: Just because you keep editing the question title doesn't make your actual question more clear.

Comment: We are not here to solve your homework. Atleast share what you have tried till now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [**`cellfun`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) and [**`strsplit`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html)  as follows:

```
NewValues = cellfun(@(x) strsplit(x, ', '), MyValues, 'UniformOutput',0);
NewValues = [NewValues{:}].'
```

Comment: Why not use `[NewValues{:}]` instead of `horzcat`? It's slightly faster, and easier on the eyes IMO...matter of taste I guess.

Comment: Hi @Sardar_Usama I have tried the above function before, this will only work with the strings, but my cell array contains characters and integers

Comment: @MohammedNadaf Then you should improve your question to show what your actual data looks like. That's not the first time you're making such mistakes

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis  I didn't know about the speed factor of those two.  Thanks for letting me know that ☺

Comment: @Sardar_Usama it's not much, but it's there.

Comment: @Sardar_Usama I don't know where I'm doing the mistake, I have written the question stating different data types and in example I have included characters and numbers, but I guess my examples are wrong. I apologize if I created any mistakes.

Comment: @MohammedNadaf My code works for the example that you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative:

```
NewValues = regexp(MyValues, ', ', 'split');
NewValues = [NewValues{:}]';
```

which works on the example you posted, but judging from your comments, it wil not solve your actual problem.

So please post an actual example of your actual problem, and we'll be able to help you ***MUCH*** quicker and better.

Comment: @Sardar_Usama yes, I spotted the typo just before your comment, but thanks! In the context of cell arrays, there is no difference between the `ctranspose` and `transpose` operators. Also I just used the transpose to make the output agree with what the OP posted, but it might not even be necessary...

Comment: I deleted my comment when I saw that you had fixed it.